# Thread interrupted status is not cleared when InterruptedException is thrown

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

Can someone explain why this program prints multiple "interrupted" statements.

According to Thread.sleep javadoc

> InterruptedException - if any thread has interrupted the current thread. The interrupted status of the current thread is cleared when this exception is thrown.

```
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        for (int z = 0; z < 100; z++) {

            ExecutorService executor1 = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

            executor1.execute(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    ExecutorService executor2 = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

                        executor2.execute(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    Thread.sleep(1000 * 100);
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()) {
                                        System.out.println("interrupted");
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    executor2.shutdownNow();
                    try {
                        executor2.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            });

            executor1.shutdown();

            try {
                executor1.awaitTermination(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[output - screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zWpj.png)

Comment: Please be specific. What exactly do you have problem with in this code?

Answer (score 2):

From the [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt())

> If this thread is blocked in an invocation of the wait(), wait(long),
>   or wait(long, int) methods of the Object class, or of the join(),
>   join(long), join(long, int), sleep(long), or sleep(long, int), methods
>   of this class, then its interrupt status will be cleared and it will
>   receive an InterruptedException.

The status is cleared when you shutdown the executor service during `Thread.sleep(1000 * 100)` and `InterruptedException` is thrown.

But the ThreadPoolExecutor re-set the status by `t.interrupt()`, so you can still get the status.

Here is a piece code of reset status:

```
    for (Worker w : workers) {
        Thread t = w.thread;
        if (!t.isInterrupted() && w.tryLock()) {
            try {
                t.interrupt();
            } catch (SecurityException ignore) {
            } finally {
                w.unlock();
            }
        }
        if (onlyOne)
            break;
    }
```

Comment: You mentioned that the ThreadPoolExecutor catched the InterruptedException. I don't think applicable here. The code is catching the InterruptedException thrown by the thread himself, so the exception won't propagate to the ThreadPoolExecutor

Comment: @Ashutosh A My mistake, I just checked the code and edited my post.

Answer (score 1):

*THIS ANSWER IS WRONG (keeping it as is so that people know that this code fragment is NOT the cause)*

The `Executors.newFixedThreadPool()` method returns a `ThreadPoolExecutor`

If you look at `ThreadPoolExecutor.shutdownNow()`, you'll see that it interrupts the workers potentially twice -

```
public List<Runnable> shutdownNow() {
        List<Runnable> tasks;
        final ReentrantLock mainLock = this.mainLock;
        mainLock.lock();
        try {
            checkShutdownAccess();
            advanceRunState(STOP);
            interruptWorkers(); //First interrupt here
            tasks = drainQueue();
        } finally {
            mainLock.unlock();
        }
        tryTerminate(); //Second interrupt here
        return tasks;
    }
```

So it must be that some threads are getting interrupted twice.

The first time they get interrupted, they'd come out from sleeping state and throw an InterruptedException. But right after they do that, they are getting interrupted again (before executing your code)

Comment: I'm not sure `tryTerminate` causes the second Interrupt. It calls `interruptIdleWorkers` which in turn invokes `w.tryLock()` before interrupting which will not return `true` if there are some task still running (`task.run()` is "guarded" by `w.lock()` in the method `runWorker`).

Comment: You are right, I have added a comment at the top that the answer is wrong

Answer (score 1):

In short:

You see this behavior because you have a race condition here. There is a field `ReentrantLock ThreadPoolExecutor::mainLock`. The method `shutdownNow` is guarded by it, but starting the worker thread is not.

To dig a bit deeper:

Take a look at the `ThreadPoolExecutor::execute(Runnable)`. Here is the fragment:

```
if (isRunning(c) && workQueue.offer(command)) {
    int recheck = ctl.get();
    if (! isRunning(recheck) && remove(command))
        reject(command);
    else if (workerCountOf(recheck) == 0)
        addWorker(null, false);  //add the worker to worker queue and start the thread
}
```

Now, let's take a look how the worker is started. Here is the `runWorker` method fragment (Some comments are mine):

```
// If pool is stopping, ensure thread is interrupted;
// if not, ensure thread is not interrupted.  This
// requires a recheck in second case to deal with
// shutdownNow race while clearing interrupt
if ((runStateAtLeast(ctl.get(), STOP) ||
        (Thread.interrupted() &&
        runStateAtLeast(ctl.get(), STOP))) &&
        !wt.isInterrupted()) //Was not interrupted yet by the shutdownNow method, 
                             //but the pool is being stopped
    wt.interrupt(); //<-- Interrupt it before running. 
//...
try {
      task.run();
}
//...
```

Shutting down the executor and executing the task is racy in that case.

More specifically worker thread is interrupted ***before*** the task execution is started and also ***before*** the worker's thread is interrupted by the `ExecutorService::shutdownNow` method, but ***after*** the shutdown was initiated.

If you are unlucky, the interrupted status is being updated by the `shutdownNow` method before the condition

```
if (Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
```

is checke, but after the call to `Thread.sleep(1000 * 100);` which immediately throws (because already interrupted).

***UPD***: I inserted `System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted());` before the call to `Thread.sleep(1000 * 100);` and now I cannot reproduce the case.

I can guess that now before calling to `Thread::sleep` the method `ExecutorService::shutdownNow` interrupts all thread.

***Note:*** There may well be another causes of the same behavior, but judging by the tests I ran this one seems most probable.

Comment: I think this must be it. I was debugging as-well and noticed the runWorker() method interrupting the thread before calling the run() method. Great and impressive finding!